# how to move local wamp laravel project to homestead

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have one laravel5.3 project running under the wamp. I want to move this project to homestead.

I have installed homestead and created another project which are running successfully. Now I copied my whole laravel5.3 project from wamp to homestead and also updated the homestead.yaml file accordingly. Now when I run this project in the browser, getting "This site can’t be reached".

Could any one please help me that how to move the whole project from wamp to homestead?

Thanks 
ppp

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, I forgot to update my windows\sytem32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
As I updated it, the outcome was as expected.